# How to implement rapid sorting by result of function?

Tags: performance, algorithm, postgresql, indexing

We have objects with lat and long records.
Also each object has creation date.

User can login from anywhere and see objects.
We need to show objects sorting by some special index which is calculated basing on freshness of object and how far it is from current user.

Lets say we have objects in New-York and Jersey. 
If you login from New-York you should see New-Yorks objects at the top and then Jersey ones. But nevertheless very old new-yorks objects should be below in result then new jerseys objects.

We can approximate the function F = < object freshness in day > + < distance from current user point to object's place in km >

We use PostgreSql for storing data, and we can really just sort by such function and get what we need. 
The problem is that we are afraid that it would work pretty slow because we are planning to reach like 1k-10k objects and 100-300 places and the application has to return result very quickly (because it's like the most important thing in the app)

Users will add objects from different places.

Do you have any ideas how to improve performance of such query?

Answer (score 1):

Instead you can sort according to: distance - object_creation_time. You do not need to re-evaluate this function every time you sort because its value wont change.

Comment: sorry, didnt get it, according to what? Well the function will take two arguments < lat, long > of current user. And «freshness» of objects will be changed each day.

Comment: @user909291 could you explain in more details how <<freshness>> is implemented ? Is it some numeric or date/timestamp column in a table ? What do you mean by "freshness is changed every day", is there any job running every day (or night) that calculates new <<freshness>> and updates the whole table ?

Comment: No,no. First at all it's not yet implemented, we are just thinking about it. Saying «Freshness» i mean amount of days gone from the creation date. We will have datetime field (creation date). But we can create jobs, whatever, if it would make sense

Answer (score -1):

In Postgres, indices don't have to be only on a column or tuple of columns... You can create an index on your function, as described in the [Postgres documentation.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html) If you query by the same function, the index should be used.

Comment: a function based index can be created only for functions, that refer to columns of the table. In that case the function refers to **distance from current user point to object's place in km ** , this value is not stored in the table for each object, so the function based index in this case is useless.

Comment: You're right - I missed that it was to the user's current location and not just to an arbitrary fixed point. Bleh.